# creating a list type collection for a property of node while importing CSV

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to import CSV into Neo4j and create a list collection type property to node.

I have tried with the below code but it creates multiple nodes for the values in csvline.name.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:\\persons1.csv" AS csvLine
merge (p:Persons {id: toInteger(csvLine.id), name: [csvLine.name]})

CREATE (n:Person{name:'john',age:34,gender:'m', phone_no:[1234,5678]})
```

I am expecting only one node having property with collection of phone number should be created in the above case.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `CREATE` clause is in the same Cypher statement as the `LOAD CSV`, it will be executed once for every `csvLine` value.

You will need to run the `CREATE` clause separately if you want it to be executed only once. (But you may still end up with 2 `Person` nodes with the `name`, "John", since a `MERGE` call may have already created one.)

Comment: So,what do you suggest, If I want to create just one node for Persona name "John" and want to create a property of that node as collection type which will hold multiple values of phone number.